# Recorded for each user the datetime of access and the datetime of exit in MySQL

Tags: mysql

On this table of a mysql database are recorded for each user the date and time of access and the date and time of exit :

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| tID       | tDate               | tUser | tDescription        | tSet |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 707951537 | 2020-02-11 11:17:13 | 13117 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707757026 | 2020-02-11 11:16:05 | 43409 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707765459 | 2020-02-11 09:28:42 | 16920 | ENDING  ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707765775 | 2020-02-11 09:27:13 | 16920 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707767122 | 2020-02-11 09:15:46 | 30303 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707789986 | 2020-02-11 09:13:18 | 49798 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707902406 | 2020-02-11 07:15:38 | 44333 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707917986 | 2020-02-11 07:05:57 | 43654 | ENDING  ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707918384 | 2020-02-11 07:03:30 | 43654 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707951609 | 2020-02-11 06:56:41 | 22429 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707965127 | 2020-02-11 06:08:16 | 41190 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
11 rows in set
```

I need to update the `tSet` column with the value 1 when the difference between date time entry and date time exit for each user is less than three minutes.

In this case I need this output, because for users `16920` and `43654` the difference between date time entry and date time exit is less than three minutes :

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| tID       | tDate               | tUser | tDescription        | tSet |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 707951537 | 2020-02-11 11:17:13 | 13117 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707757026 | 2020-02-11 11:16:05 | 43409 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707765459 | 2020-02-11 09:28:42 | 16920 | ENDING  ACCESS USER |    1 |
| 707765775 | 2020-02-11 09:27:13 | 16920 | STARTED ACCESS USER |    1 |
| 707767122 | 2020-02-11 09:15:46 | 30303 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707789986 | 2020-02-11 09:13:18 | 49798 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707902406 | 2020-02-11 07:15:38 | 44333 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707917986 | 2020-02-11 07:05:57 | 43654 | ENDING  ACCESS USER |    1 |
| 707918384 | 2020-02-11 07:03:30 | 43654 | STARTED ACCESS USER |    1 |
| 707951609 | 2020-02-11 06:56:41 | 22429 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707965127 | 2020-02-11 06:08:16 | 41190 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
11 rows in set
```

I have tried this sql query :

```
UPDATE `tTableUser` jjj
JOIN (
    SELECT
        a.tID,
        a.tDate,
        a.tUser,
        a.tDescription,
        TIMEDIFF(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.tDate, ' ' ,- 1),
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.tDate, ' ' ,- 1)
        ) AS strDiff
    FROM
        `tTableUser` a
    JOIN `tTableUser` b ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.tDate, ' ', 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.tDate, ' ', 1)
    AND TRIM(a.tUser) = TRIM(b.tUser)
    AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.tDate, ' ', 1) IN (
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    )
    AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.tDate, ' ' ,- 1) BETWEEN '06:00:00'
    AND '12:00:00'
    AND a.tDate > b.tDate
    AND (
        TIMEDIFF(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.tDate, ' ' ,- 1),
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.tDate, ' ' ,- 1)
        ) BETWEEN '00:00:00'
        AND '00:03:00'
    )
    ORDER BY
        a.tDate DESC
) AS xsql
SET jjj.tSet = 1
WHERE
    jjj.tID = xsql.tID;

SELECT * FROM `tTableUser`;

+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| tID       | tDate               | tUser | tDescription        | tSet |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 707951537 | 2020-02-11 11:17:13 | 13117 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707757026 | 2020-02-11 11:16:05 | 43409 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707765459 | 2020-02-11 09:28:42 | 16920 | ENDING ACCESS USER  |    1 |
| 707765775 | 2020-02-11 09:27:13 | 16920 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707767122 | 2020-02-11 09:15:46 | 30303 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707789986 | 2020-02-11 09:13:18 | 49798 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707902406 | 2020-02-11 07:15:38 | 44333 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707917986 | 2020-02-11 07:05:57 | 43654 | ENDING ACCESS USER  |    1 |
| 707918384 | 2020-02-11 07:03:30 | 43654 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707951609 | 2020-02-11 06:56:41 | 22429 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707965127 | 2020-02-11 06:08:16 | 41190 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
11 rows in set
```

Without success because the output is :

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| tID       | tDate               | tUser | tDescription        | tSet |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 707951537 | 2020-02-11 11:17:13 | 13117 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707757026 | 2020-02-11 11:16:05 | 43409 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707765459 | 2020-02-11 09:28:42 | 16920 | ENDING ACCESS USER  |    1 |
| 707765775 | 2020-02-11 09:27:13 | 16920 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707767122 | 2020-02-11 09:15:46 | 30303 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707789986 | 2020-02-11 09:13:18 | 49798 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707902406 | 2020-02-11 07:15:38 | 44333 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707917986 | 2020-02-11 07:05:57 | 43654 | ENDING ACCESS USER  |    1 |
| 707918384 | 2020-02-11 07:03:30 | 43654 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707951609 | 2020-02-11 06:56:41 | 22429 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707965127 | 2020-02-11 06:08:16 | 41190 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
11 rows in set
```

How to do resolve this ?
Please, can you help me ?

My create table code below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ttableuser`;
CREATE TABLE `ttableuser` (
  `tID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tSet` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of ttableuser
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707951537', '2020-02-11 11:17:13', '13117', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707757026', '2020-02-11 11:16:05', '43409', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707765459', '2020-02-11 09:28:42', '16920', 'ENDING  ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707765775', '2020-02-11 09:27:13', '16920', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707767122', '2020-02-11 09:15:46', '30303', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707789986', '2020-02-11 09:13:18', '49798', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707902406', '2020-02-11 07:15:38', '44333', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707917986', '2020-02-11 07:05:57', '43654', 'ENDING  ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707918384', '2020-02-11 07:03:30', '43654', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707951609', '2020-02-11 06:56:41', '22429', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
INSERT INTO `ttableuser` VALUES ('707965127', '2020-02-11 06:08:16', '41190', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
```

Comment: Each user is only recorded (at most) twice? Once when they enter, and once when they leave?

Comment: @Strawberry Each user it is recorded every time it enters and exit for current day

Comment: Does a 'day' begin after midnight, and end before midnight of the same day?

Comment: @Strawberry yes Sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table(
  `tID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tSet` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tID`)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
('707757026', '2020-02-11 11:16:05', '43409', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null),
('707765459', '2020-02-11 09:28:42', '16920', 'ENDING  ACCESS USER', null),
('707765775', '2020-02-11 09:27:13', '16920', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null),
('707767122', '2020-02-11 09:15:46', '30303', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null),
('707789986', '2020-02-11 09:13:18', '49798', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null),
('707902406', '2020-02-11 07:15:38', '44333', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null),
('707917986', '2020-02-11 07:05:57', '43654', 'ENDING  ACCESS USER', null),
('707918384', '2020-02-11 07:03:30', '43654', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null),
('707951537', '2020-02-11 11:17:13', '13117', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null),
('707951609', '2020-02-11 06:56:41', '22429', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null),
('707965127', '2020-02-11 06:08:16', '41190', 'STARTED ACCESS USER', null);
```

Assuming each user only accesses the system (at most) twice...

...and obviously add a condition for filtering on days, as necessary...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.tuser = x.tuser AND y.tid > x.tid 
   AND y.tdate < x.tdate + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| tID       | tDate               | tUser | tDescription        | tSet |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 707765459 | 2020-02-11 09:28:42 | 16920 | ENDING  ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707917986 | 2020-02-11 07:05:57 | 43654 | ENDING  ACCESS USER | NULL |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Depending on precisely which rows you wanted to amend, the UPDATE for the above could be...

```
UPDATE my_table x
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.tuser = x.tuser AND y.tid > x.tid 
   AND y.tdate < x.tdate + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE
   SET y.tset = 1, x.tset = 1;

Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROm my_table;
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| tID       | tDate               | tUser | tDescription        | tSet |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 707757026 | 2020-02-11 11:16:05 | 43409 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707765459 | 2020-02-11 09:28:42 | 16920 | ENDING  ACCESS USER |    1 |
| 707765775 | 2020-02-11 09:27:13 | 16920 | STARTED ACCESS USER |    1 |
| 707767122 | 2020-02-11 09:15:46 | 30303 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707789986 | 2020-02-11 09:13:18 | 49798 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707902406 | 2020-02-11 07:15:38 | 44333 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707917986 | 2020-02-11 07:05:57 | 43654 | ENDING  ACCESS USER |    1 |
| 707918384 | 2020-02-11 07:03:30 | 43654 | STARTED ACCESS USER |    1 |
| 707951537 | 2020-02-11 11:17:13 | 13117 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707951609 | 2020-02-11 06:56:41 | 22429 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
| 707965127 | 2020-02-11 06:08:16 | 41190 | STARTED ACCESS USER | NULL |
+-----------+---------------------+-------+---------------------+------+
```

Comment: thanks but the output on update `my_Table` not change

Comment: Okay, but I need set `tSet` column with the value 1 also for rows with `tID` **707765459** and **707917986** with `tDescription` equals to `ENDING  ACCESS USER`

Comment: Two sql queries ?

Comment: Thanks but If added on the sql query an `AND y.tdescription = 'ENDING ACCESS USER'` no row is updated ... what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207656/discussion-between-golia-and-strawberry).